# Combine Two Oracle Queries

Tags: sql, oracle

I am a beginner to oracle/sql. I can write basic queries but now I am getting in over my head. I have two queries that I would like to combine. The output I am looking for is like so (in one row):

Batch #
Status
Minutes
Page Count

Here are the two **separate** queries:

```
   SELECT aq.batchnum, aq.status, (dateended - datestarted) * 24 * 60 minutes
    FROM archivedqueue aq INNER JOIN scanninglog sl ON aq.batchnum = sl.batchnum
   WHERE     aq.datestarted BETWEEN TO_DATE ('27-MAY-2014 00:00:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
                                AND TO_DATE ('29-MAY-2014 23:59:59', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
         AND sl.usernum = '3724'
         AND sl.actionnum = '200'
ORDER BY aq.batchnum DESC;


SELECT COUNT (*)
  FROM archivedqueue aq
       INNER JOIN itemdata id ON aq.batchnum = id.batchnum
       INNER JOIN itemdatapage idp ON idp.itemnum = id.itemnum
       INNER JOIN scanninglog sl ON aq.batchnum = sl.batchnum
 WHERE aq.batchnum = '648353' AND sl.actionnum = '202';
```

I was trying to do something like this, but I am unsure of how to link the batchnum from the result in q1 to the query in q2

```
    SELECT q1.batchnum,
       q1.status,
       q1.minutes,
       q2.page_count
  FROM (  SELECT aq.batchnum, aq.status, (dateended - datestarted) * 24 * 60 minutes
            FROM archivedqueue aq INNER JOIN scanninglog sl ON aq.batchnum = sl.batchnum
           WHERE     aq.datestarted BETWEEN TO_DATE ('27-MAY-2014 00:00:00',
                                                     'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
                                        AND TO_DATE ('29-MAY-2014 23:59:59',
                                                     'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
                 AND sl.usernum = '3724'
                 AND sl.actionnum = '200'
        ORDER BY aq.batchnum DESC) q1,
       (SELECT COUNT (*) page_count
          FROM archivedqueue aq
               INNER JOIN itemdata id ON aq.batchnum = id.batchnum
               INNER JOIN itemdatapage idp ON idp.itemnum = id.itemnum
               INNER JOIN scanninglog sl ON aq.batchnum = sl.batchnum
         WHERE sl.actionnum = '202' AND aq.batchnum = q1.batchnum) q2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give you the non ANSI SQL version, given you're running in an Oracle DB (which I prefer :) ):

```
  SELECT aq.batchnum,
         aq.status,
         (dateended - datestarted) * 24 * 60 minutes,
         COUNT (*) page_count
    FROM archivedqueue aq,
         itemdata id,
         itemdatapage idp,
         (SELECT *
            FROM scanninglog
           WHERE usernum = '3724' AND actionnum IN ('200', '202')) sl
   WHERE     aq.batchnum = id.batchnum
         AND idp.itemnum = id.itemnum
         AND aq.batchnum = sl.batchnum
         AND aq.batchnum = '648353'
         AND aq.datestarted BETWEEN TO_DATE ('27-MAY-2014 00:00:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
                                AND TO_DATE ('29-MAY-2014 23:59:59', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
GROUP BY aq.batchnum, aq.status, (dateended - datestarted) * 24 * 60
ORDER BY aq.batchnum DESC;
```

Comment: I should have added in my initial post. A batchnum can't be specified in the second query because there will be a lot of batch numbers and I need the page counts for each of those batch numbers.

Comment: Did you try running my SQL?

Comment: Yes. I get zero results but I assume it is for the reason mentioned above.

Comment: Comment out the batchnum or usernum or actionnum, that may be why, right?

Comment: Date? I would run the query without any hard conditions, see what you get, if nothing, then the joins may be wrong, but those were provided by you... soo....

Comment: Can't remove the date. There are millions of records and that could take 30 minutes just to test. I can tell you, that the separate queries worked with data returned.

Comment: I found a bug, hold on

Comment: Perfect. I really appreciate this!

Comment: Did it return back the results you were looking for? If so, please accept my ans

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to make use of the GROUP BY function. It's hard to be sure without knowing your table structures and so on, but it might look something like this:

```
SELECT aq.batchnum, aq.status, (dateended - datestarted)*24*60 Minutes, count(*)
FROM archivedqueue aq
     INNER JOIN scanninglog sl
     ON aq.batchnum = sl.batchnum
     INNER JOIN itemdata id
     ON aq.batchnum = id.batchnum
     INNER JOIN itemdatapage idp
     ON idp.itemnum = id.itemnum
WHERE (
      aq.datestarted 
      BETWEEN TO_DATE( '27-MAY-2014 00:00:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) 
      AND TO_DATE( '29-MAY-2014 23:59:59', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' )
      )
AND sl.usernum = '3724'
AND sl.actionnum = '200'
GROUP BY aq.batchnum, aq.status, (dateended - datestarted)*24*60
ORDER BY aq.batchnum DESC
```

Comment: I wish I knew how to implement this. Thank you for the help but I receive this error:  ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 17 Column: 16

Comment: Hmm weird, still receiving the same error. Sorry I am new I have no idea what is causing this.